# Count the number of times a word in a specific order (Unix)

Tags: unix

count how many times A and B shows up in this example file:

```
Ex:  
1,2,3,A  
2,3,1,A  
3,1,2,A  
1,2,3,B  
1,3,2,B
```

Expected Output should be:

```
A 3  
B 2
```

So far I have:

```
    grep -cw "*A" <file>
```

with output: 
3

Which only displays the number of occurrences.

Comment: How do you define a word? Strings separated by space? Will there be multiple occurrences of the word in a single line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking for. Do you want to write a shell script? Then: for which shell?

Comment: Try 'uniq -c <file>'   It finds unique lines in its input and the '-c' adds the count to each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat t1.txt 
1,2,3,A
2,3,1,A
3,1,2,A
1,2,3,B
1,3,2,B

mayankp@mayank:~/$ awk -F, 'NR{arr[$4]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}' t1.txt
A 3
B 2
```

Let me know if this helps.